# Restoring an Analytic Function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Restore the analytic function $f(z)$ if its imaginary part $v(x,y) = -\frac{y}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$ and $f(2)=2$.

Now, $v_y = \frac{-[(x-1)^2 + y^2] - (-y)(2y)}{[(x-1)^2 + y^2]^2} = \frac{-x^2+2x-1-y^2+2y^2}{[(x-1)^2 + y^2]^2} = \frac{-x^2 + 2x-1 + y^2}{[(x-1)^2 + y^2]^2} = u_x$

So normally from here I would take $u = \int \frac{-x^2 + 2x-1 + y^2}{[(x-1)^2 + y^2]^2}dx + \phi(y) = \frac{x-1}{x^2 - 2x+y^2 + 1} + \phi(y)$.

So $u_y =$ ...

Is this the right direction? I do not really understand?